не получается решить задачу
Не идёт код к задаче, помогите, пожалуйста, решить её на Python
Задача  Чехарда
Дорожка замощена плитками в один ряд, плитки пронумерованы числами от 1 до 1000. На плитках с номерами A, B и C  (A<B<C) сидят три кузнечика, которые играют в чехарду по следующим правилам:

На одной плитке может находиться только один кузнечик.

За один ход один из двух крайних кузнечиков (то есть с плитки A или с плитки C) может перепрыгнуть через среднего кузнечика (плитка B) и встать на плитку, которая находится ровно посередине между двумя оставшимися кузнечиками (то есть между B и C или A и B соответственно). Если между двумя оставшимися кузнечиками находится чётное число плиток, то он может выбрать любую из двух центральных плиток.


Например, если кузнечики первоначально сидели на плитках номер 1, 5, 10, то первым ходом кузнечик с плитки номер 10 может перепрыгнуть на плитку номер 3 (она находится посередине между 1 и 5), или кузнечик с плитки номер 1 может перепрыгнуть на плитку номер 7 или 8 (эти две плитки находятся посередине между плитками 5 и 10).
Даны три числа: A, B, C
. Определите, какое наибольшее число ходов может продолжаться игра.
Входные данные
Программа получает на вход три целых числа A, B и C (1≤A<B<C≤1000), записанных в отдельных строках.
Выходные данные
Выведите одно число — наибольшее количество ходов, которое может продолжаться игра.
Примечание к примеру
В примере сначала кузнечик с плитки №6 прыгает на плитку №3. Затем кузнечик с плитки №4 прыгает на плитку №2.
Примеры
Входные данные
1
4
6

Выходные данные
2

Выдает ошибку на тесте 4 и 60 баллов из 100, но какая ошибка посмотреть невозможно:
a = int(input())
b = int(input())    
c = int(input())    

d = (c - b) + (b - a) - 2    
s = 0    
while d > 0:    
    s += 1    
    d >>= 1

print(s)


Почему не получается? Кто куда не идёт?

:((  Помогите, пожалуйста, вместо того, чтобы кидаться сарказмом

@Оксана, учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

@insolor Оксана же написала: "не идёт код".

@rotabor вот и нужно выяснить что именно это значит.

@Оксана добавьте в вопрос ваш (даже нерабочий) код.

@чистов_n добавила неполноценный код

А не будет ли случайно результат равен числу битов (битовой длине) в максимальной из разниц (c - b) и  (b - a)?

Смысл контестов тогда вообще пропадает.

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

d = max(abs(c - b), abs(b - a))
print(max(d.bit_length() - 1, 2) if d > 1 else 0)


@Lith , увы, снова ошибка на тесте 4

Задача решается аналитически элементарно:
=INT(LOG2(2*MAX(B-A,C-B)-1))

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
# Option 1
from math import log2
d = max(b - a, c - b)
print(int(log2(2 * d - 1))) 
# Option 2
d = max(c - b, b - a) - 1
print(d.bit_length())

Поскольку нужно найти наибольшее число шагов, то начинаем с большего промежутка d = max(b - a, c - b), что сводится к расположению { A = B - d; B; C = B + d }. С каждым шагом промежуток уменьшается вдвое, поэтому количество шагов равно двоичному логарифму от первоначального расстояния между двумя соседними кузнечиками d. Если очередной промежуток d чётный, то следующий выбирается d/2. Для любого натурального n количество решений для промежутков 2n и 2n+1 одинаковое.
Варианты решения эквивалентны, так как d.bit_length() equals int(log2(d) + 1).


from math import log2

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

d = max(abs(b - a), abs(c - b))
print(int(log2(2 * d - 1)))


@Lith С bit_length тоже решается, но немного не так, как вы сделали: a = int(input()) b = int(input()) c = int(input()) d = max(c - b, b - a) - 1 print(d.bit_length())

@Lith подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этом коде работает логарифм? Такого еще не проходили с преподавателем (((

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

d = max(abs(b - a), abs(c - b))
x = 2 * d - 1
log2_x = 0
while x > 1:
    x >>= 1
    log2_x += 1
print(log2_x)

Просто используем существующую стандартную библиотеку Python math. При помощи from мы обращаемся к библиотеке чтобы подобрать необходимые нам функции при помощи import. В нашем случае мы подбираем log2 функцию из под библиотеки math.

@Lith и rotabor   спасибо огромное. Оба кода работают на 100 баллов. Осталось только понять как, чтобы объяснить преподавателю.

@rotabor, вы смелый человек. Я потратил полтора часа на написание объяснения, откуда логарифм берётся и бросил не доведя до конца: никто не стал бы такое читать.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Как я уже прокомментировал где-то, главное - не бздеть. В конце концов, расхлёбывать будет Оксана :-)

@StanislavVolodarskiy Смелость - это когда приезжаешь на завод, останавливаешь установку и начинаешь что-то делать, а через несколько часов её нужно запустить...

@StanislavVolodarskiy Одно из определений, которое можно дать логарифму, в точности объясняет решение задачи: Логарифм заданного числа по указанному основанию - это как раз такое число, целая часть которого показывает, сколько раз нужно разделить заданное число на основание до получения частного в пределах между основанием и единицей включительно.

@rotabor огромное спасибо.
